# How to use Material Chips with MDCOutlinedTextField Swift5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I want to add chips with outlined textfield like this UI

[image: Chips + outlined textfield]

How can i do this in swift?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Set Stroke color to clear `textfield.setOutline(Color: .clear, forState: .normal)`
may be this will help you.